# Warning: include(File.php) failed in Autoload.php on line 93

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, compiler

I have followed several articles on this, but none solve my problem. Every request on site writes the following entry to the system log.

`var/log/system.log`:

```
2013-10-09T12:53:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(File.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/public_html/domain.com/live/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-10-09T12:53:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'File.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/local:/var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/community:/var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core:/var/public_html/domain.com/live/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /var/public_html/domain.com/live/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I have seen and followed articles that indicate this is related to the compiler.

### What I've Done So Far

I have commented the two lines out in `includes/config.php`.

Cleared the profiler from terminal following Mr Storm's article: [Magento Compiler](http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path).

Ensured that the caches are emptied and indexing has been run several times.

Compared a vanilla copy of 1.7.0.2 CE and looked for any files that my own codebase might be missing (using WinMerge).

Disabled symlinks in admin.

Changed file permissions to several various recommendations and back again.

---

I've also noticed that the profiler page in admin located at `Admin > System > Tools > Compilation` is completely blank, apart from the nav and footer.

Any help on where to now would be very appreciated. Please ask if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Go to `/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93` and use Mage's `mageDebugBacktrace()` (it's a function, so call it directly). See where did that File.php came from. Use `if ($class === 'File') { mageDebugBacktrace(); }` so it won't print on every class autoload. I had a similar issue with Ecomdev's PHPUnit module.

Comment: So helpful (for many applications), thanks very much!

Comment: If you only see a blank page - its worth to take a look into the source code

Comment: Try to recompil the code<br>
System -> Tools -> Compilation -> Run compiation process <br>
and Refresh cache.

Comment: @nevvermind i included this code `if ($class === 'File') { mageDebugBacktrace(); }` in  `lib/varien/autoload.php` as here : http://pastebin.com/yiZ0cjVy , but still it gave me same issue....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Autoload tries to require the file for a class that isn't found in the code base yet. Since it is requiring `File.php` it stands to reason that *somewhere* in the code the class `File()` is called which doesn't exist yet in your codebase.

If you track down the spot where that class is instantiated you will have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

For follow-up, the `mageDebugBacktrace()` provided the following result:

```
[1] :
[2] :
[3] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php:199
[4] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php:119
[5] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
[6] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/Mage.php:462
[7] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:401
[8] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:295
[9] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:337
[10] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/app/Mage.php:683
[11] /var/public_html/domain.com/live/index.php:71
```

Looking at the `Cache.php` file, I can see that the 'File' part is the default backend cache type used by Magento, if none is specified. I changed my `app/etc/local.xml` file to use 'File', note upper case 'F':

File `app/etc/local.xml`:

```
<cache>
    <backend><![CDATA[File]]></backend>
    ...
</cache>
```

Hope that helps someone out.

Comment: I do not know why Magento documents stuff like that falsely, but the uppercase 'F' did it for me.

Comment: @Jongosi, your solution is worked for me. Thank you very much. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered a weird **Warning: include(somefile.php) failed in Autoload.php on line 93** after pulling work on a shared test environment and someone else enabled the cache.

Not this exact case, because it's mentioned:

> Ensured that the caches are emptied and indexing has been run several
>   times.

So, always remember to check and disable/clear the cache if working on a shared environment, before wasting hours debugging!

Answer (score 1):

It could be also issue with apc cache. **Restart apache2** or execute `apc_clear_cache();` from php

Answer (score 1):

This error while creating an object from class like `$obj = new GoogleClient();` in Magento it try to find out the class file using `Autoload.php`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and turns out flushing the redis cache fix it for me.

From command line:

`echo 'flushall' | redis-cli -s /path/to/sock`

Heres the documentation incase you're not using a socket:

https://briansnelson.com/Install_Redis_Caching_for_Magento

Hope that helps.