# Customer records won't open 500 error

Tags: http-error-500

When trying to load customer records in Magento we get a 500 error.  This is what's in the logs.  Running Magento ver. 1.9.3.9, any help appreciated.

> 2018-08-29T12:48:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   include(Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /home/sitename/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   2018-08-29T12:48:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   include(Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /home/sitename/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>   2018-08-29T12:48:50+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/sitename/public_html/app/code/local:/home/sitename/public_html/app/code/community:/home/sitename/public_html/app/code/core:/home/sitename/public_html/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear')
>   in /home/sitename/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: please try one of solution from this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/warning-includefile-php-failed-in-autoload-php-on-line-93/35912 Question